# Integration Testing Framework

Tags: c#, integration-testing

I'm looking for a framework to help automate my integration tests. C# / VS2013.

The requirements are basically exactly the same as for a unit testing framework, except that I need to be able to specify the order that tests are executed in, because the tests are affecting a database (which is wiped at the start of the test and is always in a deterministic state throughout the tests) and gradually building up a very large number of products and other items which all interact with each other.

I'm currently using MbUnit / Gallio, but it seems like they've ceased development and can't launch VS2013 to debug. Is there anything else out there?

And I'm saddened by having to add this, but what I DO NOT NEED is people telling me how unit tests ought to be independent and mock the database layer. I've got unit tests, thanks. They don't give me enough coverage of some of the interactions I need to test, which is why I am automating integration testing *in addition*.

Comment: I'm not familiar with a good framework especially for this, but if it were me I might consider using the same framework I was using for unit testing, except writing the tests out separately and then having one actual method marked as a test that executed each step in order and then asserted it was successful.

Comment: I write my integration tests alongside my unit tests. I have not had the thought that I needed an integration test framework before.

Answer (score 1):

Visual Studio's unit test framework (mstest) has "Ordered Test" that will allow you to specify test execution order.

You can run tests in an order from command line through /testcontainer:test.dll /test:test1 /test:test2 /test:test3. Moreover the tests will run on alphabetical order.

Answer (score 0):

maybe this links help [ordered execution of tests in visual studio](http://Controlling%20execution%20order%20of%20unit%20tests%20in%20Visual%20Studio)

There is also a design pattern described by martin fowler [Gateway](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/gateway.html)